# trying to ensure 'cookies' are set with httpOnly attribute in IIS

Tags: asp.net, http, security, iis, httponly

I am trying to ensure 'cookies' are set with httpOnly attribute in IIS, which from reading hundreds of articles it seems is simple but why does my security scan keep failing.

I have added `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />` to the system.web section of the web config but still it fails so what am I missing ?

I am running IIS 8 on W2012 R2 with .net 4 in the application pool ?

Any help is greatly appreciated as I have spent hours going round in circles on this !

Thanks

Comment: Which cookies are we talking about here? The forms auth cookie? Session cookie? Or custom cookies that your application uses?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the httponly to ture in the web.config? If this is your requirement, I suggest you could try to use this setting: <httpCookies domain="String" 
             httpOnlyCookies="true|false" 
             requireSSL="true|false" />. Then you could try to use F12 develop tool to see if the httponly is in the request header.

Comment: Hello and I appreciate your time, I am trying to fix a CISCAT vulberability namely this :                                                                   Ensure 'cookies' are set with HttpOnly attribute


Description:

The httpOnlyCookies attribute of the httpCookies node determines if IIS will set the HttpOnly flag on HTTP cookies it sets. The HttpOnly flag indicates to the user agent that the cookie must not be accessible by client-side script (i.e document.cookie). It is recommended that the httpOnlyCookies attribute be set to true.
I have added the code it advises but still fail

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get this resolved? I'm also having the same issue as yours.